# Converting millimiters to Cocoa points

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, paragraph, measurement

ALL,

[This page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMutableParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableParagraphStyle/setFirstLineHeadIndent:) states that I need to pass points to this function.

What is considered a "point" for Cocoa and how do I convert a millimeters to points?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally there are 72 points to an inch. On screen however that only works for displays hat have 72 dpi. Today many displays have slightly above 100 dpi.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)

So there are about 2.83pt (72/25.4) per mm.

Comment: so is it 72/25.4 or 100/25.4?

Comment: When you print it it should come out as 72/25.4. When you display it on older computer screens it should come out as 72/25.4. When displaying on newer computer screens it comes out at 100/25.4. Unfortunate, but it is what it is. If you want absolute sizes on a given screen, you need to find out the screen resolution. You can always run a test: render some text at 72pt. When printing it should come out as 1" text, on the screen it may be smaller.